# emulator and phone code run well but when APK release it didnt work

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i working on a flutter app. and when it run it goes well. on the mobile phone and the emulater.here is the screenshot, [emulator work fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRZNd.jpg)
but after i create an APK. it shows only white screen. i cant show the code now. but can you show me the wrong. [after install APK screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HbCa.jpg) 
a

Answer (score 0):

You need to set internet permission in your android manifest for it to work

To do that, go to -- *your-project\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml* and paste this code  **`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`**

[image]

Comment: this permission is i already added.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue of build-mode, release/debug.
if the apk was built in release mode and there's an issue let's say Null check error
A grey screen will be used to hide it i.e. in release mode. This wouldn't be the case for debug mode.

So I suggest you check the logs for any error, exceptions or error you may have ignored in logs.

Comment: Thanks.this is the error that i have getting..this can be the error?
.════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Comment: yeah that's one of the issues that may cause that grey screen to show probably not on debug but on release.